# C# websocket flow control for real time data

Tags: c#, websocket, tcp

I am looking for web socket based solution to dissipate real time stock quotes in c#, I have tried supersocket c# library, it works well but if client end is not accepting data due to any reason, packet drops starts

So I will be happy to check some option of TCP flow control based on client's internet speed or capabilities, I have seen light streamer has something in place but that is for fixed number of items, while in stocks number of items are not pre decided

Comment: Try SignalR.  It's a .Net library that supports websockets and allows users to be organized into groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) might be what you are looking for.  It supports various web communication protocols including websockets and allows advanced user management such as user groups. Make sure to use the .Net Core version instead of the .Net ASP.

You can force it to only use websockets but there is no real reason to do this as it will select websockets by default if both client and server support it.

Comment: Why .NET core instead of  .NET  4.7 etc? Any specific reason?

Comment: The libraries and protocols are different. The framework version will no longer get new features, only bug fixes.